# Problem finding roots of a depressed quartic using the Ferrari Method.

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, roots, factoring, quartics

I attempted to follow the [Ferrari method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution) for a depressed quartic as described at wikipedia for the function $x^4+5/8x^2-5/8x-51/256$

The roots are $-1/4, 3/4, -1/4-i$, and $-1/4+i$. However, when I follow the method, I get a $1/4, -3/4, 1/4-i$, and $1/4+i$, or each root times $-1$.

I followed the process with other depressed quartics, and sometimes they were correct, and sometimes they were, again, the negative of the correct value.

For the quartic in question, I calculated the resolvent cubic of $x^3+5/8x^2-5/8x-51/256$. Which has one real root, m = 1/8. When I use this m, I get the negative of each of the roots.

I actually went through the derivation, and it seems correct. Does anyone have any insight as to why it is sometimes incorrect?

Edit: Here is the process as laid out on Wikipedia:

$$y^4+\frac{5}{8}y^2-\frac{5}{8}y-\frac{51}{256} = 0$$

Add $\frac{p^2}{4}$ to each side: $(y^2 + 5/16)^2 = 5/8y + 9/64
$

Add $2y^2m + pm+m^2$ to each side: $(y^2 + 5/16 + m)^2 = 2my^2 + 5/8y + m^2 + 5/8m + 9/64$

Set discriminant to zero and solve for m: $8m^3+5m^2+\frac{19}{8}m-\frac{25}{64}=0$

Use real root: $m=\frac{1}{8}$

Final equation is: $\left(y^2+\frac{5}{16}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{5}{8}\right)\left(y^2+\frac{5}{16}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{2}y-\frac{5}{8}\right)$

or: $\left(y^2+\frac{27}{16}+\frac{1}{2}y\right)\left(y^2-
\frac{3}{16}-\frac{1}{2}y\right)= 0$

The roots of the right side are $-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$

I'll simplify the wikipedia final equations for comparison.

Comment: Have you substituted the proposed roots into the original equation - that should give you a definitive answer as to which are the correct roots.

Comment: Yes, I added a section to my spreadsheet to substitute my calculated value back in to verify that it was zero (or close to it). I also added the ability to multiply the calculated root by -1 to see if that fixed it. Every random number I threw at it was either correct, or off by the -1. However, I would like to fix the wikipedia article along with my algorithm so I don't have to check every answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve equations by Ferrari's method in the following stile.

We need to solve
$$256x^4+160x^2-160x-51=0$$ or
$$(16x^2+k)^2-((32k-160)x^2+160x+x^2+51)=0.$$

Now, we'll find a value of $k$, for which

$(32k-160)x^2+160x+x^2+51$ is a square.

For which we need $$80^2-(x^2+51)(32k-160)=0$$ or
$$k^3-5k^2+51k-455=0$$
and since $7$ is a divisor of $455$, we get a multiplier $k-7$, which gives
$$(k-7)(k^2+2k+65)=0$$
or $k=7$ only.

Thus, we need to solve
$$(16x^2+7)^2-(64x^2+160x+100)=0$$ or
$$(16x^2+7+8x+10)(16x^2+7-8x-10)=0$$ or
$$(16x^2+8x+17)(16x^2-8x-3)=0$$ and the rest is smooth.

Comment: Thanks for providing this summary, Do you have any insight into where the wikipedia article fails?

Comment: @Kevin Nowaczyk Wikipedia says about this method, but I showed how it works.

Comment: According to wikipedia, if $y^4+py^3+qy+r=0$, then the resolvent cubic is $8m^3+8pm^2+(2p^2-8r)m-q^2 = 0$. This differs from the one you have. I worked out the derivation as well earlier.

Comment: @Kevin Nowaczyk This resolvent of another equation. The resolvent of your equation is $x^3-5x^2+51x-455=0$. The way, which I showed, you can get a resolvent for any equation with degree four.

Comment: Is there a general expression to produce this cubic from the quartic different from the one I gave?

Comment: @Kevin Nowaczyk Yes, of course, but it's very ugly. For the generalization you can use the way,  which I showed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57308/discussion-between-michael-rozenberg-and-kevin-nowaczyk).

Answer (score 0):

The roots of

$$y^2-\frac y2-\frac3{16}=0$$ are indeed $\color{red}-\dfrac14$ and $\color{red}+\dfrac34$.

Seems that you need to review your quadratic solver :)